# Create Tree on a grid with ten segmented line with genetic algorithm

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I have some segmented lines on a grid such as the attached figure. I want to run a genetic algorithm on such chromosome and create some trees at the end of run. I can not find a suitable fitness function the bias our algorithm toward creating tree. Do you have any idea for the fitness function?

the figure can be found in the following link:

http://8pic.ir/images/9ef8b719finoswm83kf9.jpg